# Selecting specific values on a Chart

Tags: c#, select, charts, mschart

I'm trying to create a sort of copy and paste function with the data on my graph and I was wondering if there was any way to get the x position of a point on the chart when it is clicked?

Basically, the idea is to be able to click a portion of the graph and drag to select an area, which I will then process accordingly.

So, I need to be able to figure out where on the graph the user has clicked to determine the what the first point of the selected area will be.

I looked through the chart API, but I couldn't seem to find anything useful for this type of problem..

Comment: Text block try to change it C# code block.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For directly clicking on a `DataPoint` you can do a `HitTest`. But for tiny points or for a selection of a range this will not work well.

The necessary functions are hidden in the `Axes` methods.

This solution uses a regular rubber-band rectangle to select the points caught:

[image]

```
Point mdown = Point.Empty;
List<DataPoint> selectedPoints = null;

private void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mdown = e.Location;
    selectedPoints = new List<DataPoint>();
}

private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        chart1.Refresh();
        using (Graphics g = chart1.CreateGraphics())
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, GetRectangle(mdown, e.Location));
    }
}

private void chart1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    Rectangle rect = GetRectangle(mdown, e.Location);

    foreach (DataPoint dp in chart1.Series[0].Points)
    {
        int x = (int)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue);
        int y = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[0]);
        if (rect.Contains(new Point(x,y))) selectedPoints.Add(dp);
    }

    // optionally color the found datapoints:
    foreach (DataPoint dp in chart1.Series[0].Points)
        dp.Color = selectedPoints.Contains(dp) ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
}

static public Rectangle GetRectangle(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return new Rectangle(Math.Min(p1.X, p2.X), Math.Min(p1.Y, p2.Y),
        Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X), Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y));
}
```

Note that this will work for `Line, FastLine and Point` charts. For other types you would have to adapt the selection criterium!

Comment: Thank you! The ValueToPixelPosition function is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: One more quick question. Do you know of any easy ways to change the colour of the line between the points instead of changing the colour of the points themselves since I'm using a FastLine chart?

Comment: Not possible for `FastLine`. Use `Line` if you want this and other extras, Then you can set the `Color` of each `DataPoint`.. - If you are happy with an answer, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!