# How to get selected chart area data in C#

Tags: c#, csv, charts, mschart

I plotted a graph by using .csv file.Now user enable to select the chart area and clicking export button then selected data want to write another .csv file.
In here I want to approach this methods.User want to get `chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionStart`,`chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionEnd`then want to read .csv file and deleting others raw that in not selected area.
Note:the user want to select multiple chart area also.Please give me a clarification about this.This is winform application and I use MsChart.
my code as follows;

```
 private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     List<Graph> ObservingData = new List<Graph>(); // List to store all available Graph objects from the CSV
     int index = 0;
     using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\CSVFile\NEWFile\Export\NewFile.csv"))
     {
         // Loops through each lines in the CSV
         foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathToCsv))
         {
             // here line stands for each line in the csv file
             string[] CsvLine = line.Split(',');

             // creating an object of type Graph based on the each csv line
             // and adding them to the  List<Graph>
             Graph Instance1 = new Graph();

             if (index == 0)
             {
                 sw.WriteLine(line);
             }    
             else
             {
                 //Add the code here..
                 //  if (((chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionStart))<=  && ( <= (chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionEnd)))
                 {
                     sw.WriteLine(line);
                 }                       
             }
             index++; 
         }
         sw.Close();
     }
     MessageBox.Show("Data are copied to the new .CSV file");
 }
```

Following code for my multiple selection for chart area.

```
        SizeF curRange = SizeF.Empty;
        List<SizeF> ranges = new List<SizeF>();
        List<int> selectedIndices = new List<int>();

      private void chart1_SelectionRangeChanged(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
            {

                ranges.Add(curRange);
                selectedIndices.Union(collectDataPoints(chart1.Series[0],curRange.Width, curRange.Height)).Distinct();

                StripLine sl = new StripLine();
                sl.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, Color.LightSeaGreen);
                sl.IntervalOffset = Math.Min(curRange.Width, curRange.Height);
                sl.StripWidth = Math.Abs(curRange.Height - curRange.Width);
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Add(sl);           

            }
            List<int> collectDataPoints(Series s, double min, double max)
            {
                List<int> hits = new List<int>();
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Points.Count; i++)
                    if (s.Points[i].XValue >= min && s.Points[i].XValue <= max) hits.Add(i);           
                return hits;
            }

      private void chart1_SelectionRangeChanging(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
            {

                curRange = new SizeF((float)e.NewSelectionStart, (float)e.NewSelectionEnd);
            }
```

Following code is plotted graph;

```
  private void Output_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<Graph> ObservingData = new List<Graph>(); // List to store all available Graph objects from the CSV

            // Loops through each lines in the CSV
            foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathToCsv).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
            {
                // here line stands for each line in the csv file

                string[] InCsvLine = line.Split(',');

                // creating an object of type Graph based on the each csv line

                Graph Inst1 = new Graph();


                Inst1.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(InCsvLine[0], dateFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 

                Inst1.AvE = double.Parse(InCsvLine[15]);
                Inst1.AvI = double.Parse(InCsvLine[16]);

                chart1.Series["Speed"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
                chart1.Series["Velocity"].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
                chart1.Series["Speed"].Points.AddXY(Inst1.Date.TimeOfDay.ToString(), Inst1.AvE);
                chart1.Series["Speed"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
                chart1.Series["Velocity"].Points.AddXY(Inst1.Date.TimeOfDay.ToString(), Inst1.AvI);
                chart1.Series["Velocity"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
                ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
                CA.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
                CA.AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
                CA.CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
                CA.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;

            }
        }
```

[This is out put of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aH2p.png)

Comment: you may want to look at [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056264/selecting-specific-values-on-a-chart/40057669?s=1|1.4196#40057669)

Comment: @TaW thank you for giving that.but it is not helpful for my question.I could plot a graph by getting .csv file.but now I want to get selected area data to the another .csv file.In here I want to whole .csv file data with all columns with selected data area result only.please give me a solution for this.

Comment: Well, once you have the list of selected points, what stops you from exporting them to a new csv file? It is up to you to decide if the point indices of one series will fit other series in other chartareas and of course if any other data are missing.. Note that each DataPoint can have a Tag and you can hold the whoe line from the csv file in it.. Looiking closer I have my doubts now: WhatChart are you using? MSChart? What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: @TaW this is winform application and I use MSChart.

Comment: @TaW. firstly I plotted a chart by using .csv file's data.Now I want to this,the user selects some areas of this chart and export those selected chart area data to new .csv file.So in here I hoped to get chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionStart,chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionEnd .this code and check whether old .csv file condition is true.then the selected data between this area then print those data to new .csv file.And user can select multiple chart area.

Comment: Well, ok. Do add the proper Tags then, please. And what is Graph? Did you say it can already display the data?  (An image often helps)If you are using the MSChart control: How do you add the DataPoints?

Comment: You need to match the selected DataPoints with the data in the file. So the if condition will check if the corresponding data point (i.e. X,Y pair) matches with data value from the line you read. You have not shown what is Graph and also no info which values from the csv file are mapped to the X and Y on the chart.

Comment: @MukulVarshney thank you for your help.I tried that but I can not do how I compare X and Y in Line.In comparing line how I get column value.Can you give some extra clarification about that.It will help to improve my code.

Comment: @SNP, X and Y are nothing but the values used to plot the Series in ChartAreas[0]. As per your question, this series is been created from a csv file. So definitely, you have a column in csv file representing X or Y. Now from the selected data points match them with corresponding column values in CsvLine and save them in new csv file.

Comment: @MukulVarshney I added my whole code this question.please look at that and Give me extra clarification about this question

Comment: @TaW I also added my whole code.If you can give me clarification regarding my problem.I want to select the multiple selection on the graph area and user click the export button then want to read the .csv file and save multiple selected chart area details only  in new .csv file.as like this  original file delete unselected area details .please give me a solution for my matter.

Comment: @TaW.I am block with code sir,If you can please give me a suitable way to solve my problem.

Comment: @TaW I do not have any person in clear my problem.Sir,please give me a solution.It is great help for me to solve my coding problem.

Comment: OK. Which part is it you have problöems with? Geting a `List<DataPoint>` of selected points? Or writing a CSV file from them? - Also: Do all the Series from the ChartAreas have the same number of datapoints and the same x-values? What info, precisely must be written out? Without these infos neither you nor anybody else can do it.. - Also: I still have no idea what that `Graph` class is you seem to be using??

Comment: @TaW I want to select the multiple selection on the graph area and user click the export button then want  save multiple selected chart area details  in new .csv file.

Comment: @TaW It just like this,we think we have 100 raws 10 columns in .csv file and draw a chart by getting those data.after plotted graph I selected some areas of chart just think I select  10-25 raws and 60-90 raws.now I click export button then I want those selected area data save  in my new .csv file with that 10 columns.Graph class that is store data I read from .csv file.Sir,is it clear?

Comment: Well, no. I see nothing about how (or even if) Graph is created or even used for anything at al. I also see only one ChartArea, from the looks with two Series. Worst of all I see that you are adding the x-values as strings. This is a serious problem as this looses the actual values (event though they are shown in the labels). Do change this and add them as what they seems to be: DateTimes or else you won't be able to properly use them e.g. to identify the selected DataPoints!!! Once you got that up and running do post the new code and a screenshot of the new chart with its data..!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example you may want to study.

It assumes that the x-values are added as `DateTimes`; set the `XValueType`!

```
eachSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
```

It also assumes that you have a class level List of sereis to be exported:

```
var series2Export = new List<Series>() { chart.Series[0], chart.Series[1]};
```

It assumes further that the points in the series are added in parallel, so that you want to export the same range together, e.g. to first 20 or points from index 33-66..

Now you can for example code the `SelectionRangeChanged` event (or, of course a *Save* `Button` click):

```
private void chart_SelectionRangeChanged(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
{
    ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];

    var d0 = (int) ca.CursorX.SelectionStart;
    var d1 = (int) ca.CursorX.SelectionEnd;
    var spoints  = series2Export[0].Points
                                   .Where(x => x.XValue >= d0  && x.XValue <= d1).ToList();
    string del1 = ";";
    string del2 = "\t";
    string fmt1 = "yyyy.MM.dd";
    string fmt2 = "#0.0";

    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.FileName = suggestedFilePath;
    sfd.Title =  (d1 - d0) + " points selected. Save data to..";
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var dp0 in spoints)
        {
            int pi = chart.Series[0].Points.IndexOf(dp0);
            string st = "";
            foreach (var s in series2Export)
            {
                DataPoint dp = s.Points[pi];
                st +=  (DateTime.FromOADate(dp.XValue)).ToString(fmt1) +
                       del1 + dp.YValues[0].ToString(fmt2) + del2;
            }
            sb.AppendLine(st);
        }
        File.WriteAllText(sfd.FileName, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

}

Note that I have used strings for both the delimiters and the formts of the data. You can adapt them as needed..

The above code is exporting the data from all participating series in the format: *x-value1, yvalue1..*; this means it assumes that..

- the datapoints contain all the information you want to export and
- you want to export the x-values for each point.

If you want to export just the csv line as you had read it in, the simplest way is to store that line with each `DataPoint`, of, say the 1st series. The natural spot to store them in are the `Tags`.

Here are two functions to create a list of data points from a line and to restore that line from a series:

```
List<DataPoint> PointsFromCsvLine(string line)
{
    var parts = line.Split(',').ToList();        // use your separator
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(parts[0]);  // add checks!
    double d1 = Convert.ToDouble(parts[1]);      // use..
    double d2 = Convert.ToDouble(parts[4]);      // ..your..
    double d3 = Convert.ToDouble(parts[9]);      // ..numbers!

    var points = new List<DataPoint>();
    points.Add(new DataPoint(  dt.ToOADate(), d1));
    points.Add(new DataPoint(  dt.ToOADate(), d2));
    points.Add(new DataPoint(  dt.ToOADate(), d3));
    points[0].Tag = line;
    return points;
}

string CsvLineFromPoint(Series series0, int index )
{
    DataPoint dp = series0.Points[index];            // check index
    string s = dp.Tag.ToString();
    return s;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help.I am trying to get your path now.

Comment: Do ask when you run into questions!

Comment: ,I didn't get my hoped result sir,but thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you can, do decribe how the result differs from what yo expected. Did you use the functions at the end?

Comment: ,I added my output window to this question.In here I wish to get in as follows;I want to add here to this chart window that user need to give multple selection or one selection,he want to give X axis selection and then want to click Export button then want to save those selected area data to new .csv file.As I mentioned above my comments,I want to read all details about my previous .CSV file and want to save those selected area data only.How I do that.Please sir,If you can give me a solution for this.It is very help for me.

Comment: For mulitple selections the CursorX properties alone will not be enough. You also need to store and best highlight the previous selection. As my last remark at the then end explain you can store and then export the fuill csv lines by keeping them with the datapoints.

Comment: ,Sir,I am learning about this language in alone.That's why I asked from you sir,I tried my best to do this.Please give me help for this

Comment: @TaW.please can you explain this code part..eachSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;what I want to add this eachSeries?

Comment: I tried  your code but not save the selected area data to new .csv file.please give me a help sir

Comment: In here I want like this.I want to delete unselected area data  by comparing from original .csv file and save selected area data in new .csv file.

Comment: I could got result in marked answer but in here I can get one last selection data only from multiple section,So how I correct that answer for multiple selection how I do that.Give me a solution sir