# Find points between minimum and maximum range on Point Chart .Net

Tags: c#, .net, charts, annotations

I'm writing a simple C# windows app that gets some data from users and shows those on a Point chart.

The chart is like this:
[image: Point Chart]

The blue line is expected points and the red lines are the minimum and maximum range of points that can be acceptable. All of these lines are LineAnnotation. Now I want to count the points between the minimum and maximum range. How can I do this?

Creation of LineAnnotation:

```
LineAnnotation maximum = new LineAnnotation();
maximum.Name = "Maximum";
maximum.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
maximum.AxisX = chartFrequence.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
maximum.AxisY = chartFrequence.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
maximum.AnchorX = 4.9 //X POINT OF ANNOTATION START;
maximum.AnchorY = 11 //Y POINT OF ANNOTATION START;
maximum.Height = -1;
maximumDown.Width = 1; 
maximum.LineWidth = 2;
maximum.LineColor = Color.Red;
maximum.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
chartFrequence.Annotations.Add(maximum);
```

Comment: Do you have the equations of the minimum and maximum lines? Just check all the points against them.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056264/selecting-specific-values-on-a-chart/40057669#40057669) is an example that lets you select all points in a rectangle. You can instead create a GraphicsPath and test all DataPoints against the GraphicsPath. Use the data from your LineAnnotations to create th GraphicsPath! – Can you show how exactly the LineAnnotations are created?

Comment: @AndrewMorton that lines just have a start point, width, and height

Comment: @TaW Thank you. I added the code of LineAnnotations creation.

Comment: OK, this looks ok. One thing: If you want the Annotations to be moveable you will need to use the then current X and Y values, which are not set before moving. Best set them right before the AnchorX/Y values. - Then you calculate the four points with the respective axes functions like in the link. Finally you create the GP and loop over each datapoint checking gp.IsVisible(pt)..

Comment: `PointF p1 = new PointF((float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(la1.X),
    (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(la1.Y));
PointF p2 = new PointF((float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(la2.X),
    (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(la2.Y));

PointF p3 = new PointF((float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(la1.X + la1.Width),
        (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(la1.Y + la1.Height));

PointF p4 = new PointF((float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(la2.X + la2.Width),
        (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(la2.Y + la2.Height));`

Comment: `gp.AddPolygon(new PointF[] { p1, p3, p4, p2});

foreach (DataPoint dp in s.Points)
{
    PointF pt = new PointF((float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue), 
                            (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[0]));
    if (gp.IsVisible(pt)) dp.Color = Color.Orange; else dp.Color = s.Color;
}`